# Is there is a way to set DataRow RowState to ADDED without a for loop

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I have this `DataTable` dt which has about 3000 rows, I would like to set all rows to ADDED, this is taking a little bit longer than I'd like with a `foreach` loop.

```
sqlcommand = "Select Asset_ID, LaneNo, AadtCount, CommVehCnt From " + lineXTableName;
dal.setCommandText(sqlcommand);
System.Data.DataTable dt = dal.ExecuteDataTable();
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    row.SetAdded();
}
```

Is there some faster way to call `SetAdded()`?

Comment: I doubt the loop is what is taking longer. That should be pretty fast. I have a feeling the query is the bottleneck not the loop.

Comment: You are spot on thanks for that, should have tested the exact row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodingYoshi was correct in the comments lag was coming from a different spot.